# Office how to create a custom shape with an adjustable yellow point?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, shapes

I've seen that it is possible to draw custom shapes in Word or PowerPoint and copy paste them and use them between the programs. Now in the point editor there is no option to make a point adjustable. All I know is that if I have a complex shape in Word that I want to make look good in PDF (without these white lines between each other, not sure what it is anti aliasing or something). I went in PowerPoint and merged them together and put them back, that worked well so far.

Now I'm still wondering how can I create a custom shape with an adjustable yellow dot, like seen in the image. Probably requires to edit word files or something.

[image]

Comment: For triangles, you can just use `Insert -> Shapes` in either Powerpoint or Word. But somehow I have the feeling that is not the answer you are looking for. To get a different one, you  may need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can't do what you're after.

When you merge shapes, the result is an entirely new shape, a Freeform. Any "adjustment" handles are lost along with the original merged shapes.  Freeforms don't have adjustment handles; only some of the predefined shapes built into PPT have them.